# Update OpenMPI version 2.1.1 to version 4.1.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmpi

To run a specific set of code I require the latest version of ompi.

To do this I followed this video:
https://youtu.be/QIMAu_o_5V8

All seems to work well however, when I restart my laptop and check the version of ompi (ompi_info), it still states the original (older) version of ompi.

I've appended the following to my .bashrc file:
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/openmpi/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/openmpi/lib

I'd be most grateful for any pointers on how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the changes you made to your .bashrc file are not being loaded when you start a new terminal session. Here are some things you can try:

Make sure you are using the correct version of the .bashrc file. Check that you have made changes to the correct file and that it is located in your home directory.

Check that the changes you made to your .bashrc file are correct. Double-check the syntax and make sure there are no typos or errors.

Try running the following command in your terminal to reload your .bashrc file: source ~/.bashrc. This should reload your .bashrc file and apply any changes you made.

Make sure that the new version of Open MPI is installed correctly. You can check that the new version is installed by running the command which mpiexec. If the output shows the path to the new version of mpiexec, then it is installed correctly.

If none of these steps work, try restarting your computer and checking the version of Open MPI again. If the issue persists, you may need to seek additional technical support.